# `Quit` vs `ClearAll["Global`*"]`

Tags: variable-definitions

`Quit` erases all the definitions (by quitting the kernel), but so does `` ClearAll["Global`*"] `` (or other contexts). What's the difference in terms of variables in the notebook?

Comment: With respect to symbols, `Quit` has the effect of `Remove`, which "removes symbols completely, so that their names are no longer recognized by the Wolfram Language."  In contrast, `ClearAll` "clears all values, definitions, attributes, messages, and defaults associated with symbols."  Following the documentation, set `a = 3`, run `Quit`, `Remove`, `ClearAll`, etc, and then execute `?a`.

Comment: An experiment for you: after running ``ClearAll["Global`*"]``, try running ``Names["Global`*"]``. Repeat the experiment, replacing `ClearAll[]` with `Remove[]`.

Comment: One follow up question: what a name without definition and attributes after `ClearAll` means? Does it signify anything?

Comment: I am not aware of any practical distinction.

Comment: So if act with `ClearAll` and then execute `Dumpsave` what will it save in .mx file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**There are significant practical differences.**

`Quit` does not "clear" anything, it instead restarts the kernel, i.e. resets it to the default state.  There is a lot of internal state that changes during the session in ways that are different from creating new symbols or attaching definitions.  So simply clearing (or removing) symbols won't reset the kernel.  Examples include:

- When you load a package, it does not only create its own context, it also causes `$Context` and `$Packages` to be modified
- Symbolic results are cached ([`ClearSystemCache`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClearSystemCache.html)) and *will actually cause symbolic processing functions to return different results than they would in a fresh session.*
- `$ModuleNumber` changes
- `Directory[]` changes
- pseudo-random number generator states change (and this also involves caching behind the scenes, which in principle affects memory usage)
- Logins to various services (e.g. `SocialMediaData`) may be remembered until the end of the session
- `In`/`Out`/`$Line` change
- Parallel kernels keep running, `ParallelNeeds` keeps remembering "needed" packages, `DistributeDefinitions` keeps remembering what was distributed
- A fresh kernel doesn't have all symbol definitions loaded.  Using various symbols [triggers loading definition and triggers loading packages](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AutomaticLoadingOfPackages.html).
- etc.

These are just a few random but concrete examples that came to mind. This list is not at all meant to be exhaustive, it is simply to illustrate how many things get modified during a session.  There are *many* more than these, very likely including many which concern the internal workings of Mathematica and we don't even know about (as they are not publicly documented).

This is all in addition to the difference between `Remove` and `ClearAll` which people mentioned in the comments and which is also significant (e.g. `ClearAll` won't help with shadowing but `Remove` will).

**In short, if you are having trouble with Mathematica, *reset it fully* by restarting the kernel, don't just clear your own definitions.**